# reading gpio with php exec failing on rc.local raspberry

Tags: php, linux, raspberry-pi, gpio, rc

I have an infinite loop in a PHP script that read my gpio (with wiringPI) in this manner

```
$newstatus = trim(exec("gpio read ".$gpioline[$i]));
```

and this line in `rc.local` to start on boot

```
php /root/CheckGPIO.php &
```

the issue is that when the script is started automatically on boot `$newstatus` is an empty string variable instead executing `php /root/CheckGPIO.php &` from the terminal once i have terminal access, all is working good and i get the gpio value in `$newstatus`

what can cause the issue?

PS. looking at output exec("whoami") script is ever executed as root

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was `PATH` not defined when the script called from rc.local